# Notes iCloud sync fail Yosemite and IOS8

Tags: icloud, macos, data-synchronization, ios, notes.app

Notes appear not to be syncing reliably. There are other questions but appear to be about older versions.

No two of iCloud, IOS and Mac seem to be fully in sync. (iCloud and IoS do appear to be in sync now) Setup is in ssytem preferences all except Back to My Mac and keychain are ticked on in the iCloud pane Mail, Calendars and Safari all sync.

Later on a retry iCloud web notes page just hangs this was after iPhones and web seemed to sync better (i.e. a iPhone test note got to the web) - get does not respond message and hit button to report to Apple. Only the notes pane is affected all others seem OK. Note this freeze happened after I wrote this - when I wrote this it seemed to react but just did not have up to date from iPhone or Mac

All my old notes seem to be OK. Probably sync by wire under iTunes before iOS8

My email seems to sync correctly

iCloud shows all notes over a year old in its list (but then shows ion screen the one I just typed in on my IPhone)

iPhone and Mac seems to be in sync for up to last Monday (Note as Monday 22nd now it looks odd for iPhone to show  Monday for notes update on 15th Dec)

How do I force a sync

How do I debug this - what logs etc

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to diagnose this with the info you've given but from experience I've found that you are able to reliably "force an sync" with any sort of iCloud data by going to System Preferences and signing out + signing back in (it'll warn you about removing iCloud data from the device, etc.)

As said in the previous answer, make sure you are syncing your notes with iCloud and not with a) another provider (Google, Exchange) or b) not syncing at all (i.e., storing locally). Verify this on the iPhone in Settings > Notes > Accounts or on the Mac with System Preferences > Internet Accounts.

The best way to see what is actually being stored in iCloud is at [its web app](http://icloud.com) like you've been doing.

Comment: "It's a bit difficult to diagnose this with the info " what extra info can I get that would be useful?

Comment: @Mark iCloud setup on both devices; specific things you've checked with iTunes sync; things you'e tried, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that, for me, removing all of the "on my Mac/iPhone" notes and dragging them into a new folder that I created within my iCloud folder... THEN most importantly disabling the "on my Mac/iPhone" notes on BOTH my Macbook and my iPhone did the trick. Disable "On My Mac" by opening notes then clicking on "notes" in the menu, then click the "On My Mac" account and it will uncheck/disable it (you must have all the items including deleted items removed first to disable.) Then, on the iPhone go into settings, notes, and toggle off the "On My iPhone" Account switch.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible some of your notes are stored 'On My Mac'.

Open Notes, select View > Show Folders List from the menu bar.

Then check if any notes are stored under 'On My Mac', if there are, drag them to 'iCloud'.

Comment: No all are in iCloud - and that does not explain why my iCloud/iPhone notes are not on my Mac